# how to make a drop down list from 2d array and display the value in input?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to display a drop down list whose entries are filled by the coder and the list is made using multidimensional array... and the value of the selected drop down should be displayed in input box.

The following one was working only with the 1d array.

Html code:

```
<form id="myForm">
<select id="selectCity">
<option>Choose a city</option>
</select>
</form>
<input type="text" name="txtprice" id="txtprice" onClick="checkPrice()">
```

Javascript code:

```
var city = new Array()
city[0][H: 1] = "Delhi";
city[1][H: 2] = "Mumbai";
city[2][H: 3] = "Bangalore";
city[3][H: 4] = "Kolkata";
city[4][H: 5] = "Chennai";
city[5][H: 6] = "Hyderabad";
city[6][H: 7] = "Ahemdabad";
var dropdown = document.getElementById("selectCity");
for (var i = 1; i < city.length; ++i) {
dropdown[dropdown.length] = new Option(city[i], city[i]);
}
var select = document.getElementById('myForm');
var input = document.getElementById('txtprice');
select.onchange = function () {
input.value = select.value;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This alters your code slightly to use an array. It is not production ready as it needs a test added to ensure that the user does not select the first option ("choose option") but is as your example.

```
var html="<option>Choose a city</option>", 
city = new Array(),
dropdown = document.getElementById("selectCity"),
select = document.getElementById('myForm'),
input = document.getElementById('txtprice');

city[0] = {name:"Delhi",value: 1,key: "H"};
city[1] = {name:"Mumbai",value: 1,key: "H"};
city[2] = {name:"Bangalore",value: 1,key: "H"};
city[3] = {name:"Kolkata",value: 1,key: "H"};
city[4] = {name:"Chennai",value: 1,key: "H"};
city[5] = {name:"Hyderabad",value: 1,key: "H"};
city[6] = {name:"Ahemdabad",value: 1,key: "H"};

for (var i = 1; i < city.length; ++i) {
    var item=city[i];
    html+="<option value='"+ (item.key+":"+item.value) + "'>"+item.name+"</option>";
}
dropdown.innerHTML=html;

select.onchange = function () {
input.value = dropdown.value;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dfch52ut/7/

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. But I want it in multidimensional array. And the input box should show H:1 or H:2 values not the index value.

Comment: The multidimentional array you propose is wrong. Does it have to be in the array, or can i store it in an array that will work, with the values, keys you propose?

Comment: I have updated the fiddle the code now produces the results that you request.

Comment: Thank u so much for the help and yes of course u can have the reward but can add reps to ur profile as i m jut new here and to give reps i should have at least 15 Reps
But once again **Thanks a lot for the help**